# Invalid token 'for' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am trying to create a for-loop that will get multiple different substrings from a large string. However, it is giving me this error:

invalid token 'for' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

I also get an error saying that index, endOfLine, indexNumber and even the i created for the for loop do not exist in this context. I understand that may be a result of it not recognizing that it is a for loop but I can't be certain.

If somebody could shed some light on how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
static char indexNumber = (char)67;
    static string mystring = "some large string";
    static int index = mystring.IndexOf(indexNumber);
    static int endOfLine = mystring.LastIndexOf("]}}]); }");

    for (int i=index; i<=endOfLine; i++)
        {
            indexNumber++;
            static int newIndex = mystring.IndexOf(indexNumber);
            string events = mystring.Substring(index, (newIndex - index));
        }
```

Comment: Is all this code outside of methods?

Comment: you cant have code (a for loop) outside of a method

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! You might need to post more code for us to see what you mean. If our guess is right then you need to read up on basic C# programming first before moving on to a system like Xamarin. Best of luck with the messy world of code ;)

Comment: That was the problem... I had it inside of my public partial class ListView : Content Page. I moved it into a new public string method and it works now, thank you for the help and sorry for asking such a simple question.. I’m very new to Xamarin.

Comment: @Yantiss like everyone else is saying, this is a basic C# issue, not anything to do with Xamarin.  If you're new to C# you might want to read up on it - here's a free book to start with: https://www.syncfusion.com/ebooks/csharp